# Android таймер или Broadcast

Tags: java, android, таймер, java-timertask

Вообщем я хочу сделать получение данных с сервера через определенный промежуток времени, промежуток времени выбирается с помощью спиннера. Вот пример кода который на данный момент есть:

```
Timer newTimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask time_to_Srever = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long time_to_server = mSettings.getLong(TimeObn, 0);

                    if (time_to_server != 0) {
                        byte time_delay_Sinhron = (byte) mSettings.getInt(SettingSinhron, 2);

                        switch (time_delay_Sinhron) {
                            case (0):
                                time_to_server += 600000;
                            break;
                            case (1):
                                time_to_server += 1800000;
                            break;
                            case (2):
                                time_to_server += 3600000;
                            break;
                            case (3):
                                time_to_server += 10800000;
                            break;
                            case (4):
                                time_to_server += 21600000;
                            break;
                            case (5):
                                time_to_server += 43200000;
                            break;
                            case (6):
                                time_to_server += 86400000;
                            break;

                            default: break;
                        }

                        long time_Now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if (time_Now >= time_to_server) {
                            Sinchron_bd.performClick();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    newTimer.schedule(time_to_Srever, 0, 60000);
```

Это скажем некая "синхронизация", но если пользователь будет находится на другом активити или приложение будет свернуто ну вообщем я боюсь что таймер не сработает, но я не умею работать с Broadcast. И собственно сам вопрос как сделать чтобы подобная "синхронизация" сработала даже если приложение свернуто ну или закрыто. Прошу помощи.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону service, даже если приложение будет закрыто, service будет работать.
А вообще через таймер обновления не делается насколько знаю, приложение будет каждый раз слать запросы  даже если нет данных для обновления и кушать батарейку..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru) или [Job Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html).
Неплохая краткая статья о планировании задач на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/336120/).

Comment: Ну, достаточно "веселые" сервисы.